# Apache doesnt start after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: apache2, upstart, init.d

during the upgrade process I was wondered for "replace init.d", and I said "keep", not replace. Now, apache2 is not working. I tried removing and upgrading again, but doesnt start.

I have this error message:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron start

Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service cron start
Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start cron
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do what it states.

Run:

```
sudo service cron start
```

or since your question references Apache:

```
sudo service apache start
```

Comment: That may be `apache2`, try thatif `apache` doesn't work